# Using arcpy.CalculateField_management

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a table with a column named "Kategorie", filled with values. I added a new column named "RULE". I want to fill this column with Strings depending on "KATEGORIE". I have a PY-Script and it doesn't work.

What is wrong?

Expression:

```
"getKat(!KATEGORIE!)"
```

Codeblock:

```
"""def getKat(KATEGORIE):
    if KATEGORIE = "0":
        myval = "Autobahn"
    if KATEGORIE = "1":
        myval = "Bundesstrasse"
    else:
        myval= 3"""
arcpy.CalculateField_management(ERG, "RULE", expression, "", codeblock)
```

---

Both answers so far don't work.
I think the problem is the line "expression" or "codeblock". I try to print the result of "myval".The result is a error message "name myval is not defined"

expression:

```
"getKat(!KATEGORIE!)"
```

codeblock:

```
"""def getKat(KATEGORIE):
    if KATEGORIE == "0":
        myval == "Autobahn"
    elif KATEGORIE == "1":
        myval == "Bundesstrasse"
    else:
        myval == "3"
    return myval"""
print "myval", myval
arcpy.CalculateField_management(ERG, "RULE", expression, "PYTHON", codeblock)
```

Comment: Where are you executing your code block? In the python window in arcmap, as a standalone script, or in the Calculate field dialog?

Comment: in your expression have you changed it to getKat(!RULE!) since this is the field you are trying to calculate?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change `=` to `==` in your `if` statements in your code block. I'd also recommend using `elif` as well:

```
"""def getKat(KATEGORIE):
    if KATEGORIE == "0":
        myval = "Autobahn"
    elif KATEGORIE == "1":
        myval = "Bundesstrasse"
    else:
        myval= 3
    return myval"""
```

In python (and most languages) `=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for comparison.

As Craig mentioned, you'll also need to `return myval` at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [Calculator Field Examples](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004s000000).

I would recommend using `elif` instead of multiple `if` statements and also using `return` instead of `myval = ""`

example:

```
if KATEGORIE == "0":
    return "Autobahn"
elif KATEGORIE == "1":
    return "Bundesstrasse"
else:
    return "other"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be what you are after - the syntax is not one that I try to remember.

I simply ran the **Calculate Field** tool once interactively using the **Expression** and **Code Block** from your question (with some minor fixes) and then did **Copy As Python Snippet** in the **Geoprocessing | Results** window to get:

```
# Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "layerName"
arcpy.CalculateField_management("layerName","RULE","getKat( !KATEGORIE! )","PYTHON_9.3","""def getKat(KATEGORIE):/n  if KATEGORIE == "0":/n    myVal = "Autobahn"/n  elif KATEGORIE == "1":/n    myVal = "Bundesstrasse"/n  else:/n    myVal = "Other"/n  return myVal""")
```

From there, as @Paul pointed out (and I had not tested), you also need to **change "/n" to "\n"** in all occurrences to get working code.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("fishnetPolys","KATEGORIE","getKat( !KATEGORIE! )","PYTHON_9.3","""def getKat(KATEGORIE):\n  if KATEGORIE == "0":\n    myVal = "Autobahn"\n  elif KATEGORIE == "1":\n    myVal = "Bundesstrasse"\n  else:\n    myVal = "Other"\n  return myVal""")
```

Comment: One thing you have to remember is to change `/n` to `\n`. I don't know why it exports this way. +1 as this way is really quick and you know what you are getting.